# Java UnMarshall XML gives null objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, resttemplate

## UnMarshalling XML gives null java objects.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
<Item Name="John"/>
<Item Name="Jason"/>
</Items>
```

Items class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items{

    @XmlElement
    private List<Item> item; 

    public List<Item> getItem() {
    return this.Item;
}

}
```

Item class :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
public class Item{

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

   public String getName() {
    return this.Name;
   }

}
```

Java Code that UnMarshalls : Here result.getBody gives XML String

```
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

 
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        
        Items itResult =  (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(result.getBody()));
```

Item object always comes null. How to unmarshall the xml correctly ?
Thanks in Advance. :

Comment: How do you use this classes?

Comment: Wheres your code that actually unmarshals the whole thing?

Comment: ``Item`` is not a ``XmlRootElement`` imho.

Comment: Yes this xml is different. It doesn't contain simple tags like <name></name>.

Comment: @SarweshSethiya what are you trying to say? It's obvious that ``name`` is an attribute.

Comment: I thought its not an attribute. Now I get it. can you help why the objects come null always ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following classes :

**Item.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
public class Item
{


   private String name;

   public String getName() 
   {
      return this.name;
   }

   @XmlAttribute(name = "Name" )
   public void setName( String name )
   {
       this.name = name;
   }

}
```

**Items.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Items")
public class Items
{

    @XmlElementWrapper( name = "Items")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();


    public List<Item> getItemList() 
    {
       return this.items;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    public void setItemList( List<Item> items )
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String... args )
    {
        try
        {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Items.class );
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Items itResult =  (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File( "Items.xml" ) );

            if ( itResult != null )
            {
                List<Item> items = itResult.getItemList();
                for ( Item item : items )
                {
                    System.out.println( item.getName() );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You should get the `Items` object which contains `Item` s.

Changes I made:

a) You need an `@XmlElementWrapper` on the list which says that the `Items` is a wrapper around `Item`s.

b) Move the `@XmlAttribute` to setter in `Item.java`

c) Move the `@XmlElement` to setter in `Items.java`

Answer (score 0):

Item Class:

```
public class Item {
    private String Name;
}
```

Items Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items {

    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Unmarshall class:

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Items itResult = (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(itResult);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Not Working, Still Items object comes null.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some `(name = "...")` in your JAXB annotations,
and therefore you got some default names not matching your XML contents.
And that's why these fields remained null when unmarshalling your XML.

#### Items.java

For field `item` you need to explicitly set `(name = "Item")`.
Otherwise you would get the default name `"item"`, which is wrong.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items {

    @XmlElement(name = "Item")
    private List<Item> item; 

    // ... getter    
}
```

#### Item.java

For field `name` you need to explicitly set `(name = "Name")`.
Otherwise you would get the default name `"name"`, which is wrong.
And by the way, you don't need `@XmlRootElement` here,
because it has no effect on non-root elements.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    // ... getter
}
```